# Short number format in Google Sheets; 1,024 → 1K, 1,816,724 → 1.8M

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, formatting

Any recipes out there for a "smart" number formatting formula for Google Sheets that's "scale-aware," a la Rails ActionView's [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) method?

I would expect to enter a number like: 1,816,724 in a cell, and via a formula, display the number in another cell formatted as: **1.8M** (or display 2,394 as **2.4K**, etc.).

Comment: It appears that you'd like to enter a number into a cell and see it formatted differently _in the same cell_. This is not something that formulas can do; a formula can't be based on the value of a cell, and would be overwritten by that value anyway. A script could replace your number with a formatted string, but they you won't have the original number there, and will not be able to use the value in calculations. So, I think the best you can do is to format the cells to use scientific notation:   1.8E+6 instead of 1.8M.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The following custom number format mask will produce the desired results without losing the accuracy of the underlying value.

```
[>999999]0.0,,\M;[>999]0.0,\K;0
```

[image: Million and Thousand number formats]

Comment: How do you add the K notation for negatives as well?

Comment: You can add up to 3 conditions and have one default.

Comment: Ah, so you cannot have M, K, as well as negative M and negative K in the same one formatting rule.

Comment: Any workarround for the negative numbers?

Comment: `[<999950]0.0,"K";[<999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"`  this custom formatting is almost perfect. How can numbers up to 999 can be excluded to be represented as is?

Comment: Amazing! It's work for me.

Comment: k should be lowercase, M and G uppercase.
Uppercase K is for Kelvin.

Answer (score 5):

This was WAY too hard to find.  Thanks for posting. Google changed the "prefix" and "suffix" settings without warning.

If you want "$" added to the beginning and 0 is 0 instead of 0.0K, you can use:

[>=999950]$0,,"M";[<=-999950]$0,,"M";$0

changes $20,000,000 into $20M

Works for charts, which is where Google changed the feature.

Answer (score 3):

found it!

```
[>=999950]0.0,,"M";[<=-999950]0.0,,"M";0.0,"K"
```

Same formula but with K, M and B!!!

And also for negatives.

Article on the matter here:
https://medium.com/@brookinc/the-only-spreadsheet-custom-number-format-you-ll-ever-need-7cc356a7ca3e

Comment: This is almost a link only answer. Please add the most relevant parts of the referred link or describe how it help you to do what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

0.0,"K" one comma gives you a number in thousands
$0.0,,"M" two commas gives you a number in thousands
It is the number of commas that matters here, not "M" or "K".

Answer (score 0):

To display both negative and positive, use the following formula in Format > Numbers > Custom number format:

[>999]$0,"K";[<999]$0,"K";$0;

Comment: Hi Diego, this answer can be improved by addressing the full question ("K" & "M").  You addressed negatives which was done in [another answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/77974/197518).  Combining everything in one clear answer would at that point make it valuable to answer this 7 year old question.