# Custom number format for large dollar amounts (positive and negative)

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I'm trying to create a custom number format that will display big dollar amounts with the typical *k*/*M* suffixes. Examples:

- $1
- $12
- $123
- $1.2k
- $12.3k
- $123k
- $1.2M
- $12.3M

And, actually, I partially managed with the custom number format:

```
$[>999999]#.#,,\M;$[>999]#.#,\k;$0
```

[image: How it looks so far]

My question is how to expand this custom number format to include negative numbers too:

- -$1
- -$12
- -$123
- -$1.2k
- -$12.3k
- -$123k
- -$1.2M
- -$12.3M

I would really like to avoid having to create an auxiliary row or column for this.

Comment: I think you are referring to [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78069), which is great but does not extend any further. To have more formatting rules than that, one has to fall back on [text concatenation in another cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/104967).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets doesn't support more than two numeric ranges in a Custom Number Format (as of July 2017).

Therefore, the answer is: not possible without an auxiliary cell.

For my particular case, where I'm displaying dollar amounts, this is the auxiliary cell. Note that it will display $12.3k with one decimal point, but $123k instead of $123.4k. Similarly for negative numbers:

`=if(A1 < -1000000, "$" & text(A1 / 1000000, "#.0") & "M", if(A1 < -100000, "$" & text(A1 / 1000, "#") & "k", if(A1 < -1000, "$" & text(A1 / 1000, "#.0") & "k", if(A1 < 1000, "$" & text(A1, "0#"), if(A1 < 10000, "$" & text(A1 / 1000, "#.0") & "k", if(A1 < 1000000, "$" & text(A1 / 1000, "#") & "k", "$" & text(A1 / 1000000, "#.0") & "M"))))))`

Almost a duplicate of [this other question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/104967), as [Alex points out](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/107743/custom-number-format-for-large-dollar-amounts-positive-and-negative?noredirect=1#comment94607_107743).